# virtual std::string name() const = 0; の = 0の用語

Tags: c++

インタフェースクラスの勉強をしていて、以下のコードがありました。

```
class Person {
public:
    virtual ~Person();
    virtual std::string name() const = 0;
    virtual std::string birthDate() const = 0;
    virtual std::string address() const = 0;
    ...
}
```

仮想メンバ関数の右側の = 0 というのはどこかの本で見た記憶があるのですが、名前と意味がよくわかりません。

検索する場合のキーワードを教えていたければ幸いです。

Comment: 純粋仮想関数 (Pure Virtual Function)

Comment: @h2so5 ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“疑似初期化子”である`= 0`を付けた仮想関数は、純粋仮想関数(pure virtual function)と言います。
また、純粋仮想関数を一つでも持つクラスは、抽象クラス(abstract class)と言います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「疑似初期化子」という言葉と抽象クラスも勉強になりました。

Comment: "擬似初期化子" もしくは "疑似初期化子" で検索しても一件も出てこないのですが…。それより規格 **9.2 Class members [class.mem]** によると `= 0` は **pure-specifier (純粋指定子)** と呼ぶ様です

Comment: @myoga ありがとうございます。確かに"疑似初期化子"では検索でこの投稿しか出てきませんでした。 「純粋指定子」勉強になりました。

Comment: [プログラミング言語C++第4版](http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/4797375957)の「20.4 抽象クラス」に、「仮想関数に“疑似初期化子”である`= 0`を付けると“純粋化”される」という記述がありますが、確かにネットでは“純粋指定子”しか見当たりませんね…。

Comment: @alpha 洋書の日本語版では「疑似初期化子」という言葉が使われているのですね。情報ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

virtual を仮想関数といい、`= 0` を付ける事で純粋である事を示します。ですのでこの関数は純粋仮想関数と呼びます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 virtualだけでは仮想関数で、=0をつけることで純粋仮想関数になるということなのですね。